# Node.JS / Passport / Sequelize - Login with wrong password

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am following this tutorial https://shorturl.at/ghnO9 using **NodeJS, Passport and Sequelize**.

The structure is pretty much the same (at least I think it is) as the Sing Up part is working fine.

However, when I sign in with a wrong password I get a successful login.

Here's how my passport.js is written:

```
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { reject } = require('bcrypt/promises');
const { resolveInclude } = require('ejs');
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(passport,user){
var User = user;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


//Login session
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy( 
{
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
 }, 
function(req, email, password, done) {
    var User = user;
    var isValidPassword = async function(userpass, password) {
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);
    }
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    }).then(function(user) {
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Email does not exist'
            });
        }
        if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect password.'
            });
        }
        var userinfo = user.get();
        return done(null, userinfo);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
        return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Something went wrong with your Signin'
        });
    });
}
));

//serialize
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null, user.id);
});

//deserialize
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
User.findByPk(id).then(function(user){
    if(user){
        done(null, user.get());
    } else {
        done(user.errors, null);
    }
});
```

I  don´t know if this is an old and obsolete tutorial and I should change some parameters. I am struggling to find any other tutorials with Passport and Sequelize, so I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please fix your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is broken (preferably - do not use link shorteners and paste the whole link in, or even better - inline the relative information in the question).

But I see your problem anyway:

1. not the cause, but still relevant - you're creating the `User` variable twice (not sure why you'd need it anyway since the `user` is available already - are you trying to alias or something?)
2. the actual problem - your `isPasswordValid` function is `async`, but you're not calling it with `await` - this results in a `Promise<boolean>` getting returned instead of just a `boolean`, and a `Promise` is always truthy, thus this

```js
if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {
```

will always evaluate to `false`, meaning the user passes the login.

---

suggestion: If you're using `bCrypt.compareSync`, the name itself suggests it *is synchronous*, meaning you do not need your function to be `async`. Here's what you need:

```
-var isValidPassword = async function(userpass, password) {
+var isValidPassword = function(userpass, password) {
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);
}
```

this would fix the problem. But we're not done yet.

Having used `bcrypt` myself, I should warn that the synchronous comparison (and hashing) should *not* be used in the context of a nodejs server, because they can slow your server down and/or block it for other users while some are trying to sign up / login etc., because the synchronous methods occupy the main thread and until that task is completed, your server cannot do anything else. For this reason, the asynchronous methods should be used (and not only with `bcrypt`, but with most utilities etc. when we're in the environment of a nodejs server).

---

In general, authentication/authorization is really easy to slip up with (just like in your case), and before you get more familiar with the general concepts of the programming language you're using apart from other factors aswell - I'd recommend to avoid trying to implement this critical layer yourself (assuming if you're shipping your application to production! For learning purposes it's fine:) ).

I'd also recommend finding a more up-to-date tutorial aswell.

Best of luck!